# XAML LongListSelector not updating item template size

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, longlistselector

I have a LongListSelector bound to an observablecollection of objects and tapping on the LongListSelector expands the tapped item vertically. However, when tapping again (it shrinks the item) the Height of the item remains as it was when expanded. This leaves a huge gap in the data listed. The problem goes away when you expand/shrink it again and this thing ONLY happens once per item, it's really quite strange. The conclusion I got to is that the LongListSelector grid in each items template is not updating correctly (it's set to Auto).

I've had a look around, and the general responses are to reset the size of the Grid in itemtemplate. Though I prefer a much more elegant solution as this requires getting the Grid and resetting it's Height value.

Here is the code for the LongListSelector:

```
<phone:LongListSelector x:Name="all_items_list" Margin="0,0,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding All_Items}" Tap="item_list_Tap" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource all_down_template}"/>
```

And it's ItemTemplate:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="all_down_template" x:Name="template">
            <Grid x:Name="grid" Margin="0,0,0,15">
                <!--Show this when shrunk-->
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" FontSize="19" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="45,0,10,0" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>

                <!-- Show this when expanded -->
                <ProgressBar Value="{Binding Percent}" Foreground="{Binding ProgressBar}" BorderBrush="{Binding ProgressBar}" Margin="34,20,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="421" Height="25" Visibility="{Binding Visibility}" VerticalAlignment="Top"/> 
            </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

But in all the examples, none are using a LongListSelector. I have looked through all the features in LongListSelector and none seem to display the selected items ItemTemplate.
Note: I can use FindName on the LongListSelector but that only gets me the DataTemplate (which I already had access to using its x:Name) and from there, I can't do anything with the DataTemplate.

If anyone knows a solution, that would be great!

Thanks.

Comment: I have same issue for LLS in WP8, in WP7 it works like a charm.
I discovered that when it shrinks my items vertically MeasureOverride and ArrangeOverride doesn’t called. And while it resized properly, these methods are called. Strange behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I worked around this bug by changing the Visibility three times, waiting for a layout pass in between each time. I did this by chaining SizeChanged handlers as shown below.

```
private void OnToggleText(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
    Grid g = (Grid)sender;
    g.Children[1].Visibility = g.Children[1].Visibility == Visibility.Collapsed ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    g.SizeChanged += g_SizeChanged;
}

void g_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Grid g = (Grid)sender;
    g.SizeChanged -= g_SizeChanged;
    g.SizeChanged += g_SizeChanged2;
    g.Children[1].Visibility = g.Children[1].Visibility == Visibility.Collapsed ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
}

void g_SizeChanged2(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Grid g = (Grid)sender;
    g.SizeChanged -= g_SizeChanged2;
    g.Children[1].Visibility = g.Children[1].Visibility == Visibility.Collapsed ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```